# Rails javascripts not updating, even when changed, committed, and pushed

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, assets

I'm having a very frustrating problem, where the changes I'm making to my javascripts aren't appearing in production, but are in development Everything works on the localhost, but not on my heroku server.

I have added an alert to be shown after the document is ready, and it isn't popping up on my heroku site. I then proceeded to copy the javascripts to a different folder, and remove the originals from the directory, commit the change, and push it. The site behaved as it did before the addition of the alert. I then reintroduced the files I had copied, committed and pushed. Still behaved as before. Through every step in the process, I have cleared my browser cache for the last month (I started the site 2 weeks ago) and increased the version number in my config/application.rb.

When I check the GitHub repo, the correct changes have been made. It's just not working in Heroku for some reason.

I have no idea what's going on. Changing any other file works.

Comment: Did you try bundle exec rake assets:precompile ?

Comment: Yes, but not `bundle exec rake assets:clean`, which worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is Rails 3, try running

```
bundle exec rake assets:clean assets:precompile --trace
```

If you still encounter errors try to review the asset pipeline http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: You would not believe the amount of time I spent on that, and the profanity of my git commit history in the process. I thank you sir.

Comment: Did it work? Even me sometimes I forget it too. When I test production mode in my local machine. I run the precompile command then when I edit in the assets folder nothing happens because Rails looks at the public folder first.

Comment: It worked. What's the difference between `assets:clean` and `assets:precompile`, and when are they applicable?

Comment: assets:clean will delete the directory/folder in public where the precompiled assets are located. Maybe it does something else too, im not so sure. Precompile will start over and precompile the assets then create the directory and files again in public. Try to look at https://github.com/ndbroadbent/turbo-sprockets-rails3 you might like it too. Its faster than the default sprockets.